# trouble geting array values after dynamically building array in jquery

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

This is probably some small thing I've overlooked. I'm trying to build a 2D array in jquery, then access it after the array is full. The array gets filled, but later the array seems to be empty. How do I access the full array?

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map;
var names = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
...
});

function createMarker(marker_id, point,street, neighborhood, date,map, infowindow, causeParam) {
            $.post('php/get_data.php', {marker_id:marker_id},
                 function(data){

                     obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                 for (var j=0; j < obj.length; j++) {

                     names.push([marker_id,objVictimdata[j].lastname]);


                 }//end for

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  id: marker_id,
                  position: point,
                  map: map,
                  icon: {
                    path: fontawesome.markers.MAP_MARKER,
                    scale: 0.5,
                    strokeWeight: 0.2,
                    strokeColor: 'black',
                    strokeOpacity: 1,
                    fillColor: '#000000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                  }
                });

               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">'+markerhtml+'</div>'); //markerhtml not included in this example
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
                    infoWindow.close();
                });

                console.log(names.length); //returns a higher number each time the loop iterates

        })//end post
        console.log(names.length); //returns 0!

};//end create marker
```

Why does it return 0 after the loop? How do I access the full array?

Comment: I tried sorting on the fly, but that was buggy. Now I'm thinking of just doing another dB call and getting my info ordered the way I want it straight from the source.

Answer (score 2):

Its an async function (your log statement is being hit while your request is still processing, hence the `null` data), you need to use callbacks:

```
function createMarker(marker_id, point,street, neighborhood, date,map, infowindow, causeParam, callback) {
    $.post('php/get_data.php', {marker_id:marker_id}, function(data) {
       ..
       ..
       callback(names)
    });
}
```

And then use the callback like so:

```
createMarker(marker_id, point,street, neighborhood, date,map, infowindow, causeParam, function(names) {
    console.log(names);
});
```

Comment: I'll have to do some research on this.

Comment: Callbacks don't seem to be what I need.

Comment: @LauraNMS -- Ehh..not sure what you mean by that - you have an async call that you want to use data from...

Comment: Yeah, @tymeJV is definitely correct. Your console.log statement is after the $.post function, which is asynchronous. So the post function runs, but doesn't wait for a response. Instead, the thread continues with your console.log line. Later, when the event listening for the post response is fired, your main thread will be interrupted to run the event handler (the callback that tymeJV suggested creating).

Comment: @tymeJV is correct - the problem has to do an asynchronous function. Thanks, tymeJV and DaveS! What I did to solve the problem was make a new php call to bring in the data I wanted in the format (alphabetized) that I wanted it.